# Not able to upload 2gb size file with struts 2.0 frmework

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, struts2, multipart

Now days all latest browser, support 2 gb size limit for file upload process,
Right now we are using following in our application
Java, JSP, Struts 2.0 framework , we did not able to upload 2gb size file, so i have search in net, i am able to find  `struts.multipart.maxSize` property configuration in `struts.xml`, i have set this value up to 2gb size, i have also set `maxPostSize` size property in tomcat `server.xml` file for increase postdata size with request.

Still we did not able to upload  2gb size file from browser.

Please some one advice us, is there any setting available in Apache server, tomcat, struts or browser, then let us know about those.

We are not using fileUpload interceptor in our file upload action

```
<action name="fileUpload" method="fileUpload" class="fileUploadAction">
<interceptor-ref name="check">
</interceptor-ref>
<result name="Errorjsp">tFrame.jsp</result>
<result name="insert">FileFrame.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and our java side action have flat logic of upload , there is no filesize limit validation  at server side code.

i want to know the reasons why large file did not upload?

for more update , we found that issue creating in our environment is CDN network. Client request through browser to send file to cdn network , and then cdn network send those file to actual server.

Issue only happen due to cdn network when we request of more than 2 gb size file,so it is not related to browser issue.

Issue not happen with cdn network , when we send out file byte to chunk to cdn network,means when we send chunk request of file byte using one java demo program. so from this analysis, we can say that cdn network work properly when we send data in chunk-ed.

and in our case we sending file upload request throgh browser, so we can't send chunk-ed request, So now my question is that is any technique or mechanism available to resolve our issue Is there any js or request mechanism available , which send chunk byte request through browser? Is there any other technique available to resolve our issue?

Thanks and regards Yatin Baraiya

Comment: And the best title is .... "Update as request by Andrea". :D

Comment: @AleksandrM Buahahaahah :D

Comment: @YatinBaraiya: you need to show HOW you upload your file serverside, with your "flat logic", because the problem may be there. BTW, why aren't you using the provided Struts2 mechanism to upload files ? :|

Comment: @AleksandrM you are no longer first with people using the [AleksandrM] tag in their questions... I won.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Well it happened to me twice, so I would say we are even. ;)

Comment: @AleksandrM fair enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 lets you upload file UP TO 2GB, that is the [maximum allowed size](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-FileSizeLimits) for a Request:

> This setting defaults to approximately 2 megabytes and should be adjusted to the maximum size file (2 gigs max) that your will need the framework to receive.

To do that, you need to set both:

1. set the common `<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2147483648" />`, for the **overall request size**;
2. set the FileUpload Interceptor parameter, both locally to an Action, or common to a package, for the **single file maximum size**:

   ```xml
   <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
       <param name="maximumSize">2147483648</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
   ```

The .2 is the missing piece in your configuration: currently, you are allowed to send 2 GigaBytes of stuff, but with a maximum filesize of 2 MegaBytes, eg. 1000 files of 2mb max each one.

Apply the above setting to your configuration to make it work, eg:

```xml
<action name="doUpload" class="com.example.UploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">2147483648</param>
    </interceptor>
    <result name="success">good_result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: If you have problems, try setting it a little lower, like 1.9GB... the request contains other data too, and maybe they used 2000000000 instead of the real number...

Comment: hi Andrea, thanks for quick reply , We are not using interceptor of fileUpload in our case , so what other limitation will cause in my case

Comment: Uh. Please edit yuor question adding details (and eventually code) related to the way you are uploading the file